# An app's window is not being drawn completely, but the window is there, can be controlled and clicked

Tags: windows

An application window is only drawn partially on the screen, but is clearly there, since it can be  moved, resized, clicked, if you know where to put the mouse.

This behaviour started occurring recently out of the blue. The application worked fine for years. Cold-Restarting the machine makes no difference. Reducing the screen resolution makes no difference.

What could the reason for this behaviour be, how could I go about debugging it?

This is on Windows Vista.

Comment: This is generally caused by a stuck thread (perhaps a busy wait loop?) that is not yeilding execution time within the process to perform the paint loop.  Isolate any worker thread code, and ensure that it sleeps occasionally  (or otherwise yeilds execution time), and rejoins the main thread when complete. Consider using Async callbacks. if you are in .net, one handy but hackish approach is to call `Application.DoEvents` every once in a while. you can also try enabling double or tripple buffering, but in that case, if it is not the issue, the window may not draw at all.

Comment: Does it only happen with one particular application or does it happen with more applications? And if its just one, whats the name of the application? Have you tried uninstall/reinstall, updating it, etc?

Comment: The application is called Lexware (popular in Germany). It happens only with it, and while it happens most of the time, intermittently it does work.